# How to change between pipewire filter-chain configs when default sink is changed

Tags: pipewire, wireplumber

If I have pipewire filter-chains set up like described here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Filter-Chain, how can I automatically switch between different sets of filters when the output device changes (like headphones <-> speakers). I assume that I have to configure wireplumber somehow but I have no idea where to start.